# Check authentication credentials using WP REST API

Tags: rest-api

I'm using the WP REST API in combination with the Application Passwords plugin. What I would like to do is simply check to make sure a username and password combination (encoded as a base64 string) is valid, but I don't see an endpoint that would correspond to this functionality. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the official Basic Authentication plugin?

https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth